binary strings have probability 0 under product measure?
I am reading Percolation by Grimmet. We consider the probability space $\Omega$ given by binary sequences (infinite) indexed by the edges of the hyperlattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$. We take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ generated by the
finite-dimensional cylinders.
We take $\mathcal{F}$ to be the $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ generated by the finite-dimensional cylinders. Finally, we take product measure with density $p$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$; this is the measure
$$ P_p = \prod_{e \in \mathbb{E}^d} \mu_e $$
where $\mu_e$ is Bernoulli measure on $\{0, 1\}$, given by
$$ \mu_e(\omega(e) = 0) = q, \quad \mu_e(\omega(e) = 1) = p. $$
Question:
My question in its most general form is: How can the Bernoulli product measure assign mass to a given sequence $\omega = (a_1,a_2,\ldots)$? wouldn't a given configuration  have an infinite number of either $0$'s or $1$'s and since $Pr(\omega) = p^{\text{number of 1's}}(1-p)^{\text{number of $0$'s}}$ this would necessarily be $0$

Yes, the probability of a single point of $\Omega$ is $0$.  This is a non-atomic probability measure. Do you have a problem with that?

Yes, every individual string has probability $0$.  This is similar to how a continuous distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, such as the uniform distribution over $(0,1)$, has probability $0$ of being equal to any particular number $x \in (0,1)$, but still has $\mathbb{P}((a,b)) = b-a > 0$.

@RobertIsrael I guess, how would you then compute probabilities with it given that you have a discrete space? How would one go about s0me computing $\Pr(A)$ for some measurable $A$ ?

@user6247850 Is there any chance you could help me answer ^ . Thank you so much

@SamaelManasseh The way to compute $Pr(A)$ depends on the event $A$.  There is no general formula for it.

@user6247850 I understand that, but is there an example you can provide me with please ?

If an event $A$ depends on only the first finitely many coin tosses, $P(A)$ can be computed by just treating it as a finite product of Bernoulli random variables.  For example, if $A = \{ \text{Sequence starts with }0 \} = \{\omega = (a_1,a_2,...) \in \Omega : a_1 = 0\},$ we have $P(A) = p$.
If $A$ depends on infinitely many coin tosses, it can be a little more complicated.  For example, if $A = \{ \text{There is at most a single } 0 \},$ we can compute $P(A)$ by defining the simpler events $A_n := \{\text{There is at most a single } 0 \text{ in the first }n \text{ terms}\}$.  We have $A \subseteq A_n$, so $P(A) \le P(A_n)$ for all $n$.  Furthermore, we can compute $P(A_n) = q^n + n p q^{n-1}$ so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = 0$.  Hence, $P(A) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = 0$, so $P(A) = 0$.
